# Why I can't call methods outside of my websocket server in Java?

Tags: java, websocket

I have websocket server class where I want to print when user connects. It works without a problem, however if I want to execute a method outside of this websocket server, it doesn't print and closes the client's connection and prints out java RuntimeException error.

```
package com.rupla.myapp.endpoint;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.websocket.EncodeException;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

import com.rupla.myapp.encoders.MessageEncoder;
import com.rupla.myapp.http.MyOtherClas;
import com.rupla.myapp.encoders.MessageDecoder;

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/chatnow", encoders = MessageEncoder.class, decoders = MessageDecoder.class)
public class WebSocketServer {

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        extracted(session);
    }

    private void extracted(Session session) {
        System.out.println("Session Opened (Client to Server) - ID: " + session.getId());
    }


    @OnMessage
    public void handleTextMessage(String message, Session s) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("New Text Message Received: " + message + " - From session: " + s.getId());
            //So here we send client's message to the client - This works
            s.getBasicRemote().sendText("Server: " + message);
        try {
            //  Here I try to print "hello" but from 'MyOtherClas'.class using printTest() method 
            MyOtherClas.printTest();
            //Right after this code, server closes the connection to the client and doesn't print anything
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("fail: "+e);
            }

    }



    /**
     * If I would call this method below, it would work since it's in the same class (but why?)
     */
    private void printInsideClas() {
        System.out.println("hello");

    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) throws IOException, EncodeException {
        System.out.println("Session Closed");
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("onError: " + t);
    }

}
```

Pretty basic websocket server for java. However when I run this on my tomcat 9.0 and connect with javascript client and try to send message from my client to the server. It closes the connection between server and client and then prints this error.

```
Session Opened (Client to Server) - ID: 4
New Text Message Received: asd - From session: 4
onError: java.lang.RuntimeException: org/apache/http/Header
Session Closed
```

I tried to google this for few days for now but still I have no answers, I really need help with this.

Comment: Change your code to print the exception stacktrace .... and show it to us.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it does give more information about the error. I do have httpClient in my lib path. It gives this error when printing stacktrace:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: org/apache/http/Header
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoMessageHandlerBase.handlePojoMethodException(PojoMessageHandlerBase.java:119)
 at 
 ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.Header
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1363)
 ... 24 more
Session Closed
`

Comment: Link for full error: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/anSAbv0Q)

Answer (score 0):

The exception is in a server-side webservices stack.  The exception is saying that it cannot load a core class that is part of Apache HTTPComponents.

Here are some possible explanations:

- Your server-side runtime is missing the JAR file.
- The JAR is present, but it is not on the right runtime classpath.
- The `Header` class depends on some other class that has *failed* class initialization.  If this has happened, there should be evidence *earlier* in the logfile.

The JAR file you should be looking for is "httpcore-.jar" or the equivalent from the old Jakarta project.

Figure out which of the above has happened, and you are close to solving the problem.